# String is getting enclosed by \ in the params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

In my get request, I am sending the parameter like this localhost:3000/home?q="item1 item2"

But in the server params if I observe the q. It changes like this.

```
"\"item1 item2\""
```

However I don't want the extra `\"` in the starting and ending of string, is there any thing I am doing wrong while sending the request?

The scenario is the same even when `q="item1+item2"`

Comment: This doesn't work ? `localhost:3000/home?q=item1%20item2`

Comment: That's not valid right?

Comment: I guess, it should work..

Comment: What is the Content-type of your get request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there are no `\"` characters in the string, it is just a way how Rails quotes `"` strings in logs. In reality, the string has a value of `"item1 item2"` and the `"` characters are part of it.

Second, if you don't want the `"` to be there, you can either just not send it - see @Sudipta Mondal:

```
localhost:3000/home?q=item1%20item2
```

or if you need to send it, then remove it afterwards in the controller:

```
params[:q].to_s[1..-2]
```

which will remove first and last character, or:

```
params[:q].gsub /"/, ""
```

which will remove all occurences of the `"`.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `q` parameter in the URL should be: `localhost:3000/home?q=item1+item2`